# Convert a 5 x 5 array (confusion matrix) into a table using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I obtained a confusion matrix using the following code,

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(train_x, train_Y).predict(test_x)
results_nm = confusion_matrix(test_Y,y_pred)
```

The output is an array [image]

I would like to plot a table using the array, with the respective values in each cell of the table.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(results_nm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.Wistia)
classNames = ['Normal','Dos', 'R2L', 'Prob', 'U2R']
plt.title('Gaussian NB confusion matrix')
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classNames))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classNames, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classNames)
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        plt.text(j,i,results_nm[i][j])
        plt.show()
```

How can I input the values of the array into each row? I get a different output with the code above.

[image]

Comment: Don't put `plt.show()` inside the `for` loop. This will erase the plot after showing the first value. `plt.show()` should only be at the end. Use `plt.text(..., ha='center', va='center')` to center the text to its cell.

Comment: Found the answer. I m closing this question. Thank you.